# ValueError while logging out user from the page dynamically created by passing pk

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

I have a page **search.html** that has a link associated with a pk that when clicked redirects to page **doc.html** which outputs the contents related to that pk

This **doc.html** extends a page **consult_home.html**. This page contains the logout button. In all the other pages that extends this **consult_home.html** the logout button works perfectly. But in the doc file I get the following error and the logout link does not work:

```
ValueError at /consultancy/doc/logout
Field 'id' expected a number but got 'logout'.
```

Below are the codes of the view functions and the url patterns and also the template codes:

**consult_home.html***

```
<button  type="button" class="button log_out" onclick="location.href='logout';">LOGOUT</button>
```

**view function for logout**

```
def logoutUser(request):                                  
    
    logout(request)
    return redirect('/')
```

**search.html**

```
<a class="judge-ttle" href="{% url 'doc' searches.pk %}">{{searches.title}}  &nbsp <i class="fas fa-external-link-alt"></i></a>
```

**views for doc.html**

```
class DocDetailView(DetailView):               
    model= Laws
    template_name = 'doc.html'
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns=[
     path('logout', views.logoutUser, name='logout'),
     path('doc/<str:pk>', DocDetailView.as_view(), name='doc' ),
]
```

As I described above the user is unable to log out when he is in **doc.html**. How can I remove this Value Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onclick` should work with an *absolute path* `/logout`, not <s>`logout`</s>:

```
<button type="button" class="button log_out" onclick="location.href='/logout';">LOGOUT</button>
```

Normally one logs out with a POST request, so it makes sense to work with a miniform that will make such request:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'logout' %}">
    <button type="submit" class="button log_out">LOGOUT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it is working now. I am beginner these suggestions are helping me alot